# openxlsx conditionalFormatting doesn't work as expected when certain characters are present in the rule

Tags: r, openxlsx

I'm using `openxlsx` to write data from a data frame to an excel file. I need the data to be coloured given some rules (eg if the value of a cell is `A1 & B1` colour the cell with red).
The problem is that this doesn't seem to work when the string representing the rule contains the following characters: `&, *`. I assume that there might be more characters having an unusual behaviour, but for these two I've experienced the following:

- `&`: if & is in the rule then the Excel file gets corrupt and it doesn't even open properly
- `*`: if * is in the rule then *all* the cells are getting coloured regardless of their content, which is not the expected outcome

Here's the code I'm using:

```
library(openxlsx)

df <- data.frame(type=c("A1 & B1","A1","B2*","A & B2","C&","C!*"))

wb <- createWorkbook("test.xlsx")
addWorksheet(wb, "Sheet1")
writeData(wb, sheet = 1, df)

style1 <- createStyle(fontColour = "white", bgFill = "red")
style2 <- createStyle(fontColour = "black", bgFill = "yellow")

conditionalFormatting(
  wb,
  "Sheet1",
  cols = 1,
  rows = 2:nrow(df)+1,
  type = "contains",
  rule = "A1 & B1",
  style = style1
  
)

conditionalFormatting(
  wb,
  "Sheet1",
  cols = 1,
  rows = 2:nrow(df)+1,
  type = "contains",
  rule = "*",
  style = style2
  
)

saveWorkbook(wb, file = "test.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

When using rules that do not include `&` or `*`, eg if we use `rule = "A1"` the behaviour is the expected and `A1 & B1`and`A1` will be coloured. To clarify using multiple rules works fine, but when a rule including `&` or `*` is used then happens what I've explained above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following [this post](https://researchwithbaxter.wordpress.com/2013/05/01/highlighting-cells-containing-an-asterisk-in-excel-pearson-correlations-in-spss/) you have to "escape" a literal `*` using a tilde. The `&` is a bit more tricky. But I remembered that I already had a similar issue when creating a `docx` and voila same solution applies here: You could replace a `&` by its html entity `&amp;`:

Note: Additionally, as I guess that you want to start the conditional formatting in row 2 ... : `2:nrow(df)+1` will add `+1` to each element of the sequence `2:nrow(df)`. To fix that use parantheses or do `1:nrow(df)+1`

```
library(openxlsx)

df <- data.frame(type=c("A1 & B1","A1","B2*","A & B2","C&","C!*"))

wb <- createWorkbook("test.xlsx")
addWorksheet(wb, "Sheet1")
writeData(wb, sheet = 1, df)

style1 <- createStyle(fontColour = "white", bgFill = "red")
style2 <- createStyle(fontColour = "black", bgFill = "yellow")

conditionalFormatting(
  wb,
  "Sheet1",
  cols = 1,
  rows = 1:nrow(df)+1,
  type = "contains",
  rule = "A1 &amp; B1",
  style = style1
  
)

conditionalFormatting(
  wb,
  "Sheet1",
  cols = 1,
  rows = 1:nrow(df)+1,
  type = "contains",
  rule = "~*",
  style = style2
  
)

saveWorkbook(wb, file = "test.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

[image]